# A program has many systems (class). Enable system to call others by class name?

Tags: c++, architecture, typeid, typeinfo

Suppose that I have a game engine.

Let's say it contains class **Graphic**, **GamePlay**, and **Physics** system.
(The real case are 20+ systems.)

All 3 of them are derived from **System**.

This is a draft of the simple initialization.

```
main(){
    Game_Engine* engine = new Game_Engine();
    Graphic* sys1= new Graphic(engine); //set to System::engine_pointer
    GamePlay* sys2= new GamePlay(engine);
    Physics* sys3= new Physics(engine);
    engine->addSystem(sys1); //add to Game_Engine's hash map
    engine->addSystem(sys2);
    engine->addSystem(sys3);
}
```

Then, I want to make all system can call each other. 
Ex. **Graphic** can call **GamePlay**.

So I design the **addSystem()** as :-

```
class Game_Engine {  
    std::unordered_map<std::type_index,Sys*> hashTable; 
    void addSystem (System* system){
        hashTable.add( std::type_index(typeid(*system)), system );
    }
    template <class SysXXX> SysXXX* getSystem(){
        return hashTable.get(std::type_index(typeid(SysXXX)) );
    }
}
```

The result is that each **System** can call each other by using only class name :-

```
class Graphic : public System {
    void call_me_every_time_step(){
        engine_pointer->getSystem<GamePlay>()->... do something ;
    }
}
```

Now, it works as I wished, but

1. I heard that typeid is bad for performance.
2. **Game_Engine.h** now has to #include all **Graphic.h**, **GamePlay.h** and **Physics.h**, so compilation time increases.
   (I tried to not include them -> typeid of 3 derived System will return wrong result.)

Is it possible to avoid those drawback?   How?
Are there any other disadvantage?
Is this a bad design in the first place?   If so, what is a good design?
(because I have very limited experience on C++.)

**Edit 1 : Below section responses to gudok's answer**

Adding a certain get/set function for each system is what I did.

However, I realized that it become harder to manage when there are more systems, at least for me.

I ran away from it and use the template code instead, as above.

For gudok's solution,  a single system will increase programmer's work as followed:-

1. add the field declaration in the "GameEngine"
2. add another function to return a certain system
3. when rename a class e.g. "Graphics" to "Render" by using automatic refactor tool, I have to rename the getGraphics() to getRender() too (to make code readable)

Comparing the code in the question, a single system cost only 1 line.

```
engine->addSystem(new Graphics(engine));
```

It is not so trivial, especially when most systems are changing name, and amount of systems are increasing constantly.

**Edit 2  : Response to gudok's enhanced answer**

Make the **GameEngine** derived from **SystemHolder{T}** can reduce the work per **System** to 2 places :-

```
: public SystemHolder<Graphics>
```

and

```
engine.addSystem<Graphics>(new Graphics());
```

It is still 2 places, though.
The code in question uses only 1 place.
Therefore, it is not good enough, but thank for trying!

Comment: This looks like it's going to leak memory like a sieve. In modern C++, you should almost *never* use `new` and `delete`.

Comment: Rob K, may you provide some references (link), please?  I heard it somewhere but I don't know how to apply.

Comment: Get yourself [a good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?lq=1). C++ is really nothing like Java.

Answer (score 1):

What is the reason to use hash map and typeids instead of storing each of systems separately in GameEngine? Semantically, all these systems do different things. I'd rather do following:

```
class GameEngine {
  std::vector<System*> systems;

  Graphics* graphics;
  Gameplay* gameplay;
  Physics* physics;

  void setGraphics(Graphics* graphics) {
    this->graphics = graphics;
    this->systems.push_back(graphics);
  }
  Graphics* getGraphics() {
    return this->graphics;
  }

  ...
};
```

The idea behind this solution is that:

1. Each of systems is different from semantical point of view. When you access graphics from somewhere, most likely you will use functions specific to `Graphics` and not functions universal for all `System`s. Storing each of systems separately removes necessity for typeids and unnecessary type conversions.
2. When you need to handle all systems in some uniform way (for example, advancing game time), you use `systems` field:

   ```
   for (auto it = systems.begin(); it != systems.end(); it++) {
     it->tick();
   }
   ```

---

EDIT Here is enhanced solution. You add new system by additionally inheriting `GameEngine` from `SystemHodler`. Getting and setting instances of particular `System` is uniform by using `getSystem<T>` and `setSystem<T>` methods -- as you wanted.

```
#include <vector>

class System {
public:
  virtual ~System() {}
};
class Graphics : public System {};
class Physics: public System {};

template<typename T>
class SystemHolder {
public:
  T* getSystem() { return system; }
  void setSystem(T* system) { this->system = system; }

private:
  T* system;
};

class GameEngine: public SystemHolder<Physics>, public SystemHolder<Graphics> {
public:
  template<typename T>
  inline void addSystem(T* system) {
    systems.push_back(system);
    SystemHolder<T>::setSystem(system);
  }

  template<typename T>
  inline T* getSystem() {
    return SystemHolder<T>::getSystem();
  }

private:
  std::vector<System*> systems;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  GameEngine engine;
  engine.addSystem<Physics>(new Physics());
  engine.addSystem<Graphics>(new Graphics());

  engine.getSystem<Physics>();
  engine.getSystem<Graphics>();
}
```

Comment: Thank!, upvoted.   That is what I did.   Your reason is valid.   Can you also alleviate the issues in your solution (I updated my question), so I can accept it?

Comment: Have a look at enhanced version.

Comment: Better!  But I am afraid that it is still not good enough (I updated my question again.)  Thanks.